# Shift a plot line in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to superimpose the plots of the predictions and the actual validation values.
I am getting the following plot
[image]

I want to move the red plot to overlap with the light blue plot.

```
try1 = ts(validation_noSnoT, frequency = 7)
ses <- ets(ts(train_noSnoT, frequency = 7), model = "ANA")
ses.pred <- predict(ses, h = length(try1),level = 0)
ses.pred
plot(ses.pred)
lines(ses.pred$fitted, lwd = 2, col = "blue")
lines(try1,lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

So i did the following and it worked:

```
x_range =  seq(19057.14,by=1/7,length.out=length(noSnoT))
plot(predictions,main="Test")
lines(predictions$fitted, lwd = 2, col = "blue")
lines(x_range[(limit+1):length(value)],validation_value, col ="red")
```

What i did was to start the lines at where my training data ended. So I had to check this value manually and insert it in the seq() function. As my frequency was weekly `by` was set to 1/7. `limit` is just `floor(train_per * length(noSnoT))` where `train_per` is the training data percentage of the entire dataset
[image]